# В чем принципиальное отличие функций $APPLICATION->ShowTitle() и $APPLICATION->GetTitle()?

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите правильно ли я понимаю что show выводит а get возвращает title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это совершенно разные методы, некорректно говорить про сходство или отличие между ними.